# Google docs -- how to check for unsaved changes and comments quickly

Tags: comments, google-docs

I am editing a lot of Burundi high school seniors' college essays. So lots of suggested edits and comments. Way too frequently, I try to close the doc and it say I will lose unsaved changes. Most of the time, I can find a comment I forgot to post but not always.

1. Is there a faster way to look through a whole lot of comments to find the unsaved one?
2. When all the comments appear to be posted, what can be the unsaved change and how do I find it?

Right now I just scroll through the comments. When I can't find anything, I minimize the tab and hope they can see everything I've done when they open it.